# If statement with props react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, if-statement

For a project for my study I am working on a React Native project, but I am stuck. I want to give the prop 'Score' to Card.js and based on that score a color has to be defined; 'transparancyColor'. Currently, the props are passed from Home.js to Card.js and the transparencyColor is defined there. Is this a smart way, or do I have to do this at Home.js? And how?

The code of Card.js looks as follows:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Platform, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

const Card = (props) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    Score = props.Score
    
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Brand', {BrandName: props.BrandName, Score:props.Score })}>
            <View style={style.cardStyle}>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <Image 
                    source={require('../assets/adidas.png')}
                    style={style.imageStyle}
                    />
                    <View style={{paddingTop: '1%', paddingLeft: '5%'}}>
                        <Text style={style.BrandName}>{props.BrandName}</Text>
                        <Text>transparancy:</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={style.transparancyScore}>
                    <View style={style.transparancyBox}>
                        <Text style={style.transparancyText}>{props.Score}%</Text>
                    </View>
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons style={style.arrowStyle}name="chevron-right" size={25}/>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
//If statement I was talking about
if (Score <= 100 && Score >= 70) {
    var transparancyColor = '#52D858'
} else if(Score < 70 &&  Score >= 50) {
    var transparancyColor = '#F2B05C'
} else {
    var transparancyColor = '#FAA09E'
} 

export default Card

const style = StyleSheet.create ({
    cardStyle: {
        paddingLeft: '5%',
        paddingTop: '5%',   
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    imageStyle: {
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        ...Platform.select({
            ios: {                      
                width: 55,
                height: 55,
            },
            android: {
                width: 70,
                height: 70
            }
        })
    },
    BrandName: {
        fontSize: 20,
        paddingBottom: '3%'
    },
    transparancyScore: {
        paddingTop: '7%',
        textAlign: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    transparancyBox: {
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        height: 20,
        borderRadius: 100,
        width: 50,
        shadowColor: transparancyColor,
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 12,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.58 ,
        shadowRadius: 16,
        elevation: 24,
    },
    transparancyText: {
        color: transparancyColor,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 12,
        paddingTop: '3%'
    },
    arrowStyle: {
        paddingLeft: '5%',
        marginRight: '1%'
    }
})
```

If anyone has a solution or possible fix for this, let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the code structure question, it's fine, especially initially, to pass props down one or two levels.

In terms of code, something like that (note the convention is to start variable names with lowercase):

```
const Card = ({ Score, Brandname }) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    let transparencyColor;

//If statement I was talking about
    if (Score <= 100 && Score >= 70) {
        transparancyColor = '#52D858'
    } else if(Score < 70 &&  Score >= 50) {
        transparancyColor = '#F2B05C'
    } else {
        transparancyColor = '#FAA09E'
    } 
    
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Brand', {BrandName, Score })}>
            <View style={style.cardStyle}>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <Image 
                    source={require('../assets/adidas.png')}
                    style={style.imageStyle}
                    />
                    <View style={{paddingTop: '1%', paddingLeft: '5%'}}>
                        <Text style={style.BrandName}>{BrandName}</Text>
                        <Text>transparancy:</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={style.transparancyScore}>
                    <View style={StyleSheet.flatten([style.transparancyBox, {backgroundColor: transparencyColor}])}>
                        <Text style={style.transparancyText}>{props.Score}%</Text>
                    </View>
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons style={style.arrowStyle}name="chevron-right" size={25}/>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this myself, but got an error: "Can't find variable: transparancyColor" (in the stylesheet). How can I fix this?

Comment: Which element are you trying to color?

Comment: I am trying to color transparancyBox with element shadowColor and transparancyText with element color (see the StyleSheet)

Comment: @VladL reassignment isn't allowed with const, use var or let

Answer (score 0):

Use like this for re-assignment based on score and there is no problem using like this also.

```
let transparancyColor  = '';
//If statement I was talking about
if (Score <= 100 && Score >= 70) {
    transparancyColor = '#52D858'
} else if(Score < 70 &&  Score >= 50) {
    transparancyColor = '#F2B05C'
} else {
    transparancyColor = '#FAA09E'
}
```